# what does # (hash) do in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to angular2 . I want to know what does # (hash) do in angular2. 
e.g

```
 <ion-card #mycards1 swing-card *ngFor="let group of groups">
```

and this

```
       <ul>
          <li
          *ngFor="#Item of Items"
          (click)="onItemClicked(Item)">
              {{ Item.name }}
          </li>
       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 1 way to define a variable in typescript format.

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</div>
<input #heroInput> {{heroInput.value}}
```

An expression may also refer to properties of the template's context such as a template input variable (let hero) or a template reference variable (#heroInput).

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html